# GitHub pages are not updating automatically

Tags: github-pages, github-pages-deploy-action

I pushed a new commit to my pages https://akshatgadodia.github.io/personalwebsite/, but the new updates or content isn't showing up there.
My repo is https://github.com/akshatgadodia/personalwebsite
Everything builds and runs locally. My Git repository is up to date, and there is nothing on the GitHub status page about problems with builds, so I'm at a little bit of a loss about where to go with this. How can I get my page to update with new content that I add?